# special character in message are encoded when it's delivered

Tags: laravel-4, vonage

I'm using Laravel-4-Nexmo package to send sms but the message is encoded on delivery .

```
$receiverNumber = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$message       = "hi from nexmo ? ";
$options        = array( 'status-report-req'  => 1 );

$Nexmo = Nexmo::sendSMS('me', $receiverNumber , $message , $options);
```

and received message looks like this :

```
hi+from+nexmo+%3F+
```

I would like to receive as

```
hi from nexmo ?
```

I look forward to see what could be the solution

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of the package, I have tried but the message you sent works for me, no encoded chars.  the text uses `urlencode` function

Comment: I do not why it's not working on my side but I shifted to  [this package](https://github.com/Artistan/nexmo)  ,, anyway thanks for the great package and keep it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what was wrong with my code above, and I decided to use similar package and it works now. you can find the package here https://github.com/Artistan/nexmo

Comment: are u using laravel 4.2?

Comment: @MarlonBuendia yeah I'm using 4.2

Comment: $result = $sms->sendText('MyName','15555633637','dude, this is from a laravel package'); i did this... it says address is error

Comment: same as: $Nexmo = Nexmo::sendSMS('me', $receiverNumber , $message , $options);

Comment: If you have successfully installed that package you will have a class called **Nexmo** and use it to send just like this :   

`$receiverNumber = "phone number here";` 
`$options    = array( 'status-report-req'  => 1 ); //you can put other options you want`
`$messages    = "dude, this is from a laravel package";`

`$Nexmo = Nexmo::sendSMS('me', $receiverNumber, $messages , $options);`

Comment: @MarlonBuendia I just added this solution to the similar question you have asked ... please check it and let me know if works for you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mentioned package does not encode the given message so you should use `urlencode($yourString)` before using the pacckage

Comment: Still encoding , now getting hi%2Bfrom2Bnexmo%2B%253F$2B ; space gives %2B and '?' gives %253F ....  thanks anyway